# Direct initialization of a pointer

Tags: c++, initialization

I read some sample code in the book C++ Primer:

I do not understand how the direct initialization of a pointer works in `ps(new std::string(s))` and `ps(new std::string(*p.ps))`.
If `ps` is a pointer to string, then why is it ok to place a string as the parameter inside of its direct initialization constructor?

```
class HasPtr {
public:
   HasPtr(const std::string &s = std::string()):
       ps(new std::string(s)), i(0) { }

   // each HasPtr has its own copy of the string to which ps points
   HasPtr(const HasPtr &p):
       ps(new std::string(*p.ps)), i(p.i) { }

   HasPtr& operator=(const HasPtr &);

   ~HasPtr() { delete ps; }
private:
   std::string *ps;
   int i;
};
```

Comment: The "parameter" is a pointer, not a string.

Comment: I don't know the context of this example in your book, but be aware in general code, you shouldn't see `new std::string`, instead just use string directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `new` expression creates space for an `std::string` on the heap and returns a pointer to it. Hence, it is not a string that ps is initialized with, but a pointer to string, which ps is a type of.

Answer (score 1):

`HasPtr::ps` is a `std::string*`.

If I dereference a `std::string*` like this `*ps` I get the actual `std::string` object.

If I have an object `const HasPtr p` I can get it's member pointer to `std::string` with: `p.ps`. <sub>This is only possible inside `class HasPtr` because `ps` is `private`.</sub>

If I do `*p.ps` I will get the `std::string` pointed to by `p`'s member `std::string*`.

So the code:
    HasPtr(const HasPtr &p):
        ps(new std::string(*p.ps)), i(p.i) {}

Is using the [`std::string` copy constructor](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/) to initialize the dynamically created `std::string` that will be assigned to `this->ps` by the `HasPtr` copy constructor.